# Finding Least common multiple of numbers 1-20, getting the wrong answer

Tags: c#, lcm

I am trying to solve the Project Euler problem #5, 
"What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?"

To solve this I created methods to find the LCM (Lowest Common Multiple) using the GCD (Greatest Common Divisor)
Using the LCM method I find the LCM of the first and second prime number, then use the result of that method to find the LCM of the result and third prime number, etc, etc

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int listLength = 20;
        Boolean[] listOfNumbers = new Boolean[listLength];
        ArrayList listOfPrimes = new ArrayList();

        for (int iii = 0; iii < listLength; iii++)
        {
            listOfNumbers[iii] = true;
        }

        for (int iii = 2; iii < listLength; iii++)
        {
            if (listOfNumbers[iii])
            {
                for (int jjj = iii * 2; jjj < listLength; jjj = jjj + iii)
                {
                    listOfNumbers[jjj] = false;
                }
                listOfPrimes.Add(iii);
            }
        }

        int lcm = 1;
        for (int iii = 0; iii < listOfPrimes.Count; iii++)
        {
            lcm = LCM(lcm, (int)listOfPrimes[iii]);
        }

    }

    static public int GCD(int a, int b)
    {
        int division;
        int modulus;
        if (a < b)
        {
            int c = b;
            b = a;
            a = c;
        }
        division = a / b;
        modulus = a % b;
        if (modulus == 0)
        {
            return b;
        } else
        {
            return GCD(division, modulus);
        }
    }

    static public int LCM(int a, int b)
    {
        int lcm = (a * b) / GCD(a, b);
        return lcm;
    }
```

The actual answer is meant to be 232792560 but I get 22044 when using only the prime numbers for the LCM but 51731680 when using all 20 numbers for the LCM
Obviously neither answer was the correct one, I am just wondering am I on the right track or have I messed something up?  If possible just looking a poke in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't just primes, but their factorizations. Consider: what's the LCM of 2, 3, 4? If you just use primes, you get 2 * 3 = 6, which is clearly not a multiple of 4. What you want is the LCM of 2, 3, 2 * 2. Once you have the three numbers broken up that way, you can ignore 2, because it's obviously a factor of 2 * 2.

To extend this:

- LCM(2, 3, 4, 5) = LCM(2, 3, 2 * 2, 5) = LCM(3, 2 * 2, 5) = 60
- LCM(2, 3, 4, 5, 6) = LCM(2, 3, 2 * 2, 5, 2 * 3) = LCM(3, 2 * 2, 5) = 60

Since you just asked for a poke in the right direction, I leave the coding of this up to you. :)

Comment: Okay thank you for your response!  I understand mostly I am a little confused about that last line, why do you ignore the 2 but don't ignore the 3 for 2 * 3 since they are both factors

Comment: Ok, let me show it another way. Your original factors are 2^1, 3^1, 2^2, 5^1, 2^1*3^1. I remove 2^1 because it appears in 2^2. I keep 3^1 because there are no other factors with a higher power of 3. I keep 2^2 because there are no other factors with a higher power of 2. I keep 5^1 because there are no other factors with a higher power of 5. I remove 2^1*3^1, because I already have an equal or better power of 2 (2^2) AND an equal or better power of 3 (3^1).